# .net Mvc 5 with Vs 2013 EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When i want to sent a value as a parameter to my homecontroller.But a problem occurs.

The problem is that

EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by a usercode

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

And here is my code

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            ProductContext productContext = new ProductContext();

           Product myProduct= productContext.Products.Single(duct => duct.ProductID == id);

            return View(myProduct);
        }
```

Comment: You got to debug and see what is the innerexception details. So that and let us know the error details.

Comment: Thanks.I fixed it.The problem was,my model members's definations had to be same with it's table at the database